# FusedLocationProviderClient getLastLocation elapsedRealtimeNanos is sometimes strange

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, android-fusedlocation, fusedlocationproviderclient

I have the same problem with this.
[FusedLocationProviderClient getLastLocation elapsedRealtimeNanos mostly current system time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034473/fusedlocationproviderclient-getlastlocation-elapsedrealtimenanos-mostly-current)

My code currently compares the time value of location by FLP `getLastLocation()` with the current time value and requests a new location if 5 seconds have passed.

At some point, however, the value(current time - last location time) continues to be zero seconds. I don't know how to solve it.

The steps for requesting location are as follows:

1. Request `FusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()`
2. Determine if `lastLocation` was acquired within 5 seconds of the current time

   - Use location information within 5 seconds, end of the process
3. Request a new location update if 5 seconds have been elapsed (Request both Location manager and FLP)
4. Remove all location update requests if new locations have been updated via Location manager or FLP

   ```
   age = time diff : (SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - getElapsedRealtimeNanos() of passed location) / 1000000000L
   ```

@marilion91
If the timestamp value is still up to date, I wonder if you have confirmed that the user is likely to be in the same location.

Please advise.

Comment: why you want to get location every 5 seconds? don't you think it will consume unnecessary battery of user?

Comment: @AshwiniViolet It is not a request every 5 seconds. The app asks for a location only when it is needed. A new request is made only if the time value of the last location has elapsed 5 seconds. but sometimes age value is returned as 0, new location requests are not made.Once it's 0, the value stays at 0.

Comment: please provide the code of what you have done so far

Comment: If you just want to check the last request time then i think best approach will be,just store/replace time on every successfully request using `System.currentTimeMillis()`
and before request just put an If to compare newer one with previous(initial value will be 0). if difference is greater then 5 then do your request